# What is the meaning of "flashing a custom ROM"?

Tags: custom-roms, rom, rom-flashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc)

What is a custom ROM, and what does "flashing a custom ROM" mean?

Comment: Here's a good question about the rooting part of your question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone  (the top answer includes the whats and whys of rooting as well as the how)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note: the CyanogenMod and Fresh 3.5 links below are links to EVO Roms as an example - you need to find the correct ROM for your device**

"Flashing a custom ROM" basically means to load a different version of the Android OS.  [This site](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/01/custom-roms-for-android-explained-and-why-you-want-them/) actually explains it very well.  A custom ROM is the full Android OS customized by the ROM builder usually to make it faster, provide better battery-life or add new features.

AOSP ROMs like [CyanogenMod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=956187) offer stock Android which will remove things like HTC's Sense or Sprint's Apps.  CyanogenMod's ROM is one of the more popular ROM.

Other Roms like [Fresh 3.5](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=743079) offer a ROM very similar to the default experience (with added speed and battery-life) by leaving Sense (or whatever skin your device has) and incorporating over the air updates into an updated version of the ROM.

In order to flash a custom ROM you must first root your device. For information about rooting see Matt's comment on the OP or my original answer below:

When I had the same question this is where I found it:
http://www.talkandroid.com/7686-what-is-rooting-and-why-should-i-do-it-the-pros-cons-of-android-rooting/

Depending on what device you have the rooting method will be different though.  Personally I suggest reading up on your device at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com).

Comment: "In order to flash a custom ROM you must first root your device." Why is this the case? I believe this is a common misconception about flashing?

Comment: @jiggunjer You're right, it's not the case.  Generally you just need to unlock your bootloader and/or install a custom recovery.  The latter can be easier if you are rooted, however.