# Difference between OxygenOS and CyanogenMod 13

Tags: oneplus-x

Good day!

I've just got OnePlus X phone, E1003 model. It is equipped with OxygenOS. Also for this model [CM13](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=onyx) firmware exists.
Please explain what firmware is more suitable. And what is fundamental differences between OxygenOS and CM13.

I understand that OxygenOS v2.2.1 is built on-top of Android v5.1.1 and CM13 is built based on Android 6.x

Comment: Only nightly builds are available for CM13, so you shouldn't install them if you want the phone to work. [Here's why.](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/147830/i-installed-a-nightly-or-unstable-build-of-a-custom-rom-and-now-my-phone-doesnt)

Comment: I'm not afraid of nightly builds. They are almost stable. I used them with Xperia SP phone and there were only small bugs.