# What exactly happen when flashing new rom?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, kernel

I searched for a while without any satisfactory answer. What exactly happen when you flash a new rom on an Android device?
What the new rom contains of the Android architecture here: 
[image]

A rom (es: Cyanogen) developed for s2 can't be installed on any other device (es: note) only because of the screen resolution or there are other factors (es: drivers)?

Thanks a lot for the answers in advice :)

Comment: Please see: [What is the meaning of “flashing a custom ROM”?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6028/16575) / [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364/16575) These two questions together answer your questions.

Comment: For additional information, you might also want to visit our [rom-flashing tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info) (just updated now ;)