# How do I get SuperSU to update binaries after a reboot after using Ping Pong?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

[Screen shot of popup after reboot after checking if phone has root. So the "Grant" & "Deny" button at this point are unclickable! Why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wTcD.png)Okay so I used the latest Ping Pong root.apk from XDA to root my S6  which worked fine but yet after doing the reboot after rooting with Ping Pong and opening SuperSU it never asked me to update binaries like it's supposed to. Is that why the Root checker app says my phone is not rooted? And how can I fix it? What is causing this? Other people with my model have successfully rooted.

Model of S6 SM-G920W8
OS: 5.0.2

Comment: Try downloading the latest SuperSU zip and flash from recovery.

Comment: Where do I find the latest zip?  And what does "flash from recovery" mean?  I'm using the stock everything.

Comment: First, you should have never proceeded without proper knowledge. Currently you aren't aware of even flashing (a vital part of rooting process). In case something messes up, it would be very difficult to recover for you. Second, heres the super su zip: https://download.chainfire.eu/396/supersu/ Third, android flashing-> http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/what-is-the-meaning-of-flashing-a-custom-rom and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc I suggest you properly read these links before proceeding with anything.

Comment: I was only going to try Ping Ping nothing else since I don't know much.

Comment: CF Root?  Ping Pong comes with pre-installed SuperSU. One click root!I don't have to flash a custom ROM or a anything.

Comment: To me, it looks like the problem is in a different place than you think. Looking at your status bar, you seem to have a screen tint/filter app. Try disabling it and check if the buttons on the SuperSU popup work fine.

Comment: @Arielle THANK YOU!  You were  correct.  How did you know? Will I have to stop using the brightness app permanently?

Comment: @verve I had that problem with a Night Mode app. And no, you won't have to stop using the app permanently. Just disable it whenever you install another app that uses root permissions. You can enable it again as soon as you grant or deny those permissions to the app. And let me submit my comment as an answer...

Comment: Yes, do the answer.  Is there any way to get SuperSU to stop asking for permissions?  It's annoying to open Datasync and have ask for permissions continuously.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in a different place than you think. Looking at your status bar, you seem to have a screen tint/filter app. For whatever reason, apps like that seem to interfere with system dialogue boxes, such as the SuperSU one from your example, or the package installer. Disable the app temporarily whenever you have to deal with one of those.

Comment: The whole point of certain dialogue boxes not functioning when a screen filter is active is to avoid click-jacking - a malicious app could display a fake UI as an overlay and trick the user into giving the app e.g. root access, accessibility etc. You can disable the feature in SuperSU settings, under 'tapjacking prevention' or some such (be warned that this could lead to you giving root access to an app you do not trust).