# Need help in Upgrading My HTC Magic from Android 1.6  to Android 2.3?

Tags: updates, operating-system

i want to upgrade my HTC Magic Android Mobile form Android 1.6 to Android 2.3, before that i was curious to know what are the steps to be done for this, i downloaded Terminal Emulator in My Mobile and executed su root, it throws me permission denied, then i findout how to root a device,it gives me a warning,I want to know whether these steps are need to upgrade OS in my device, if not pls tell me steps what i have to do to upgrade the OS

Answer (score 2):

Sankar,

There's some [speculative chatter on the internet](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/10399-android-23-or-30-on-htc-magic/) to suggest you'll have a hard time running 2.3-Gingerbread on first generation Android devices (such as the HTC Dream and the [HTC Magic](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Htc_magic)). It looks like [some folks](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=873249) on XDA are working to port the OS but you're definitely looking at CyanogenMod in that case. Which means that ...

> Yes: you will have to root your phone
>   to upgrade your OS.

It also means that you might consider doing something a little less drastic, like upgrading to a somewhat more stable ROM. (Especially if the idea of rooting your phone is giving you the willies!) @matthew_read tipped me off to [the ROM Bible](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=668090) which is a great place to identify ROMs that other HTC Magic users have successfully installed. The ROMs there will still require you to root your phone, tho.

Check out the HTC Site to see if they have any supported updates though -- it looks like HTC India does [offer](http://www.htc.com/in/supportdownloadlist.aspx?p_id=272&act=sd&cat=all) at least one ROM upgrade for the Magic.

Comment: Thanks for the Info, when i went to HTc site->Support-> ROM upgrade it ask my serial Number , i gave my Serial Number, Sorry, this software download is not suitable for your device, Why you want to Upgrade my ROM , i want to upgrade Android OS, what is the relationship Between Upgrading ROM and Upgrading Android OS

Comment: Sankar, This ought to help you answer that: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc/7337#7337

Answer (score 2):

First generation devices are not seeing much support any more.

The best thing you can do is root your phone and install CyanogenMod on it. However, Cyanogenmod support for the Magic stopped at CM6, which is Android 2.2.  You will not be able to get CM7/Android 2.3 on the device this way.  There *may* be some way to get 2.3 on your phone, but you would have to see if there is anything about it on XDA forums.

[Start here for Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/htc-magic), the [wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Magic) will tell you how to root and install CM on your phone.

**YOU WILL VOID YOUR WARRANTY BY ROOTING YOUR PHONE. MAKE SURE YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE DOING. DRAGONS BE HERE.**

Comment: Are there really first generation devices that are still under warranty?

Comment: If someone is still under a 2 year contract or similar, it would void their insurance/warranty on the phone from the carrier.  So it might still be possible.  It's just a general disclaimer that you are at fault for any damage you may cause to your phone (although it is highly unlikely).

Comment: Thanks for the Info, when i went to HTc site->Support-> ROM upgrade it ask my serial Number , i gave my Serial Number, Sorry, this software download is not suitable for your device, Why you want to Upgrade my ROM , i want to upgrade Android OS, what is the relationship Between Upgrading ROM and Upgrading Android OS

Comment: @Amanda I got my Magic on the day it was released, my 18 month contract would have expired in November, but if I'd had a 24 month contract (or bought it after it had been our for a while) I'd still be in contract now. So, yes a lot of them are going to be still in contract and warranty right now. As it is my Magic was stolen and I bought out of the contract early and moved on to a Galaxy S.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which network you're on or which of the two Magic versions you've got, but there is an official 2.2 release that many networks have pushed OTA to their phones already, I know that a friend of mine who's still on a Magic got 2.2 pushed to him by Vodafone UK in December.

If you've got one of the ones that HTC update, rather than your network updating OTA, then you may be able to download the update if you go to http://www.htc.com/ and pick your country, then the Support section, then go through the Downloads available for your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can upgrade HTC Magic to Android 2.3, you just need to do some research and do some simple technical stuff. More info in this question:

[Install Ginger Yoshi 1.4 on HTC Magic 32a, which radio do I need?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12662)

Ginger Yoshi XDA thread:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=932118