# Install Ginger Yoshi 1.4 on HTC Magic 32a, which radio do I need?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, custom-roms, htc-magic, cellular-radio

My HTC Magic 32a is actually running CyanogenMod 6.1 and I'd like to switch to latest GingerYoshi 1.4 with GingerBread.

I have SPL 1.33.2010
radio 3.22.20.17

The reason I want to change is because with my sim card, cmmod seems to have problems while everything was fine when I was running Original 1.5+Sense (with radio 6.35).

Now the question, in [this xda thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=932118) about installing GingerYoshi 1.4, they say:

> if you are on 32a new radio then download the ginger yoshi 32a new radio just flash 32a new radio

What do they mean by "new radio", can I just flash back to 1.5+Sense+6.35 with RUU and then directly flash GingerYoshi over new 6.35 radio (I believe the phone would work somewhat better with a newer radio, specially regarding problems with my sim)?

Thanks

Comment: I know normally the radio is irrelevant to the rest of the ROM, but I also know the Magic is strange ... hopefully someone knowledgable comes by.

Comment: As someone who used to own a Magic 32b (until it was stolen) I remember the pain of all the subtle hardware differences and subtle oddities in those models...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now have GingerYoshi 1.5 running on my HTC Magic 32a, so I'll answer my own question and explain how it went.

As for the radio 6.35, answer is YES, you can use it with the GingerYoshi for 32a new radio.

Here is how I swithed from 2.2.1 CM6.1 radio 3.22 to 2.3.5 GingerYoshi 1.5 radio 6.35

1) I reverted my HTC magic back to the stock rom 1.5 + sense, this to simply revert to the new 6.35 radio.
I did the update by connecting the phone to usb and running the RUU
RUU_Sapphire_HTC_Europe_3.05.401.1_test_signed_NoDriver.exe

2) Then I had to reinstall a recovery, as we have radio 6.35 we need a Hero recovery, that is amonRa 1.6.2 for hero (the 1.7.0 wont work with magic)

3) I flashed 1.76.2007 SPL

At this point only thing left is to flash GingerYoshi.
From recovery, do a full wipe.
(I didn't care about having an ext partition, so I left my sdcard untouched)

4) Flashing "ginger yoshi 1.5 new radio 32a.zip" from recovery

following install procedure, answering the questions in order:
- no ext
- zeam launcher
- no swap on ext
- big density

REBOOT:
new HTC logo with hiding bugdroid

Enjoy GingerYoshi 1.5 and Android 2.3.5, so far everything seems to be working fine, and no more troubles with my simcard. Quadrant now gives 387 instead of 299 with CM6.1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the first post on that thread, on the line right below where they tell you to flash the new radio, there is a link to the bug tracker, follow that and there's a list of "General Questions". The "32a" section of those questions is:

> 32a
>
> Q: Can I use the new 6.35 radio?
>   A: NO!! it says so in the ROM's OP,
>   you should be using the old 3.22 radio, and the 1.33.2009 or 1.33.2010
>   SPL.
>
> Q: What kernel should I use?
>   A: [this one](http://www.multiupload.com/U3R6FQRHOP)...

So it looks like that's the radio kernel that you need to use?

Also at the bottom of that first post it has this line:

> ginger yoshi download folder all roms inside as well as kernels and
>   add on http://www.mediafire.com/?cabub1g3y37gj

You'll notice that folder has a file in it called "Ginger yoshi 1.4 new radio 32a.zip "

Comment: The problem is that in the download folder, there are two versions of Ginger yoshi, one named "Ginger yoshi 1.4 fix 32a/b.zip" and one named "Ginger yoshi 1.4 new radio 32a.zip" my guess would be that the former is for 3.22 radios, and the later for 'new radio', but this is confusing, what do they mean by 'new radio' if this is not 6.35?

Comment: Does it go into the descriptions of the files elsewhere in that thread? I know it's a long thread but as those files date from August, you can skip forward that far ta least.