# Improving performance of HTC Magic

Tags: custom-roms, htc-magic

I have installed Cyanogenmod 6.1 and it's OK - better app compatibility, and stable - but it's slow (and USB SD-card mounting doesn't work, but maybe that's an app or something).

What can I do to speed this thing up?

Ginger Yoshi 1.5 sounded like a good option, but I got errors when I tried to flash it.

Comment: I think this is too subjective, and you've worded it as a poll.  It would be best to browse the XDA subforum for your device and see what people say.

Comment: @Matthew Read Are you serious? 1: Best performance isn't really subjective. 2: Somebody might know the answer, and save myself and every other person to have this question, hours of reading forums. This is the point of StackExchange sites.  3: Why not submit your answer as an answer? Downvoting legit questions helps no-one.

Comment: Saying the word "best" isn't subjective is ridiculous.  My suggestion isn't an answer, and I would expect this question to be closed -- I've commented and voted while waiting to see if others agree.

Comment: MGOwen: Matthew has stated and expressed his opinion of your question. Which is perfectly fine here. I think your question is ok, *if you would rephrase it.* For example: "How can I improve the performance of the HTC Magic?" Then state in the body of the question that you are also willing to try different ROMs.

Comment: @Flow is right. As is, you're asking for people's opinions ("what do others use?") rather than for a solution to a particular problem. Further, "best performance" **is** subjective without an objective metric. What are you measuring?

Comment: I have taken a stab at making the question more about a problem to solve than to ask for opinions.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question - to speed that thing up you need to roll back to CM4 or another Android 1.6 based ROM.

I have a Magic and have used several ROMs including CMs 4, 5 and 6.  It is unfortunately hamstrung by its first-generation hardware - you simply are NOT going to get both features and speed from this phone, period.

Android 2.x ROMs do not make the Magic faster.  With all their config options they can make some things appear fast but this comes at the cost of performance in other areas.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several roms on HTC magic: Stock 1.5, Sense 1.5, CM6.1 and YoshiMod GingerBread
I always Benchmarked the phone with Quadrant for each new rom, I found out that Sense was better than plain 1.5, then CM 6.1 was faster than Sense, but the faster for me was YoshiMod with GingerBread, had no troubles with it... CM6.1 was also solid though.

Check this post for info on YoshiMod GingerBread for HTC Magic [Install Ginger Yoshi 1.4 on HTC Magic 32a, which radio do I need?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12662/install-ginger-yoshi-1-4-on-htc-magic-32a-which-radio-do-i-need)