# HDMI output from tablet

Tags: settings

My generic tablet (EZPad) has android v. 4.2.2; kernel 3.4.39+; build wing_k70-eng 4.2.2 JDQ 39.  The tablet has a HDMI port, but no apparent way of sending output.  Settings, Display shows no TVout toggle.  Any suggestions on using the HDMI port would be appreciated.

Comment: So plugging an HDMI cable into it doesn't do anything? Many devices have no specific settings, but will output automatically when a cable is plugged in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As you say, plugging an HDMI cable into it doesn't do anything.  I have a second EZPad: android 4.2.2; kernel 3.4.0+ jlingzhang@srv-fw-compile3; build full_g3702c-userdebug 4.2.2 JDQ39.  This connects through HDMI via TVout no problem.

Comment: From the table below it seems that android v 4.2.2 should not have kernel 3.4.39+.  Probably the reason that the HDMI output does not show up:

Comment: The table is shown in http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51651/which-android-runs-which-linux-kernel