# Can one determine the kernel version of a Samsung device from the Android version?

Tags: kernel, android-versions, builds

Basically, does an Android version map to a specific kernel version on Samsung devices? For example, can I assume that Samsung devices running Android 4.4.2 will have kernel version 3.4.0 (or some other version)? If not, can I tell from the build number? I am aware that [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51651/which-android-runs-which-linux-kernel) exists, but I am looking for a concise answer.

Also, related to this, does the build number of a device map to a specific Android version or are all these three properties, Android version, build number, and kernel version, independent ?

Comment: Yes they are independent in Android version and Build number but may share same Kernel version. Android version and Build number depends on manufacture/launch date of handset.

Comment: But can I tell one from the other, like what kernel version from the build number?

Comment: No.... You can not.

Comment: Anything to back that up?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Android and kernel versions are numbered independently of each other.

For example the Galaxy Note 2 (KitKat stock ROM) has a kernel version of 3.0.101. The Galaxy S4 (also KitKat) has a kernel version of 3.4.0.