# OverlayFS and external SD card

Tags: root-access, external-sd, mount

Last days I get (not so) old Samsung Xcover2, I root it and install CM 11 (KK 4.4.4).
Unfortunately Samsung GT-S7710 have small amount of internal memmory (1.18GB).

Now I want to know if there is way to mount ext4 formatted SD card as overlayFS.

Thanks.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm also looking for a way to use overlayFS with a CM machine - did you find any usefull hints?

Comment: Sorry, no luck. At the moment I use Link2SD.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real answer to your question, but it is some hopefully useful information:

according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem

"Overlayfs has been in the linux kernel since 3.18"

according to the answer and the comments here >>[Which Android runs which Linux kernel?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51651/which-android-runs-which-linux-kernel)<<

linux kernel >3.18 seems rare in Android. If your kernel is >=3.18 you may be able to use some terminal commands to manually mount it how you want, I think your best bet would be looking up linux commands for using overlayfs.