# Get the real hardware specs of fake device

Tags: hardware, tech-specs, fake-phone

I brought a new phone and it turns out to be a fake china phone.
But the settings are somehow spoofed and show fake details.
is there a way to get the real details?

**EDIT**

It is a Huawei mate 40 pro plus fake. When I go to settings and about phone, it shows android 10, RAM 12GB, storage 512GB, 10 core CPU, etc.
But all of this information is wrong, I know this as when I download just a small app of size 100MB the free storage reduces by 100GB.
RAM is not 12 GB as the device is very slow when I play some games.
Also, it seems like there are 5 rear cameras but actually only one is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify if device is reporting fake technical specs like Android version, RAM, or storage memory?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242663/how-to-verify-if-device-is-reporting-fake-technical-specs-like-android-version)

Comment: @alecxs yes, thanks a lot