# Relation between Linux and Android kernel versions

Tags: linux, kernel

I know Android is a modified linux kernel, but does that mean there is any relation between the kernel numbers?

In other words, Is kernel number (for example) 2.6.xx of Android somehow based on or modified from 2.6.xx of Linux? or is it maintained separately?

Comment: See also: [Which Android runs which Linux kernel?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51651/16575) / [What is the difference between the Linux Kernel and the Android Kernel?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47650/16575) / [Why are there so many different Android kernels](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27395/16575) / [What linux distribution is Android based on?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4339/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first guess is correct: an Android kernel is a patched version of the mainstream Linux kernel with the same version number.