# How can I enable auto-rotate for the home screen?

Tags: home-screen, auto-rotation, sony-xperia-neo-v

I have a "handset" with Android 2.3.4, and the "flip" feature works for every app and screen, except the desktop. That is, if I flip my phone any screen or app will flip too, yet the desktop remains fixed. There was an exception when I was playing a game and I pressed the home button: there the desktop was flipped, but it seems it was "forced" to flip by the game. How can I make it flip like any other app or screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it doesn't work out of the box, which is the case with many Android phones, then you have a  few different options:

- A launcher replacement which adds this feature (may not work with all ROMs)
- [A custom ROM like cyanogen mod, which has this feature built in.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) You can read more about custom ROMs [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc)
- Wait for an official update which adds this feature. (may never happen)

Answer (score 1):

*Old question, but this answer is relevant for other Android versions.*

---

I suffer from the similar problem in my Android 4.2.1 where all apps would follow auto-rotation except the home screen (default Launcher app). I found a solution mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/54167/96277) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110942/96277).

The device needs to be rooted and [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) installed. [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) is the app that did the job in my device.

### Instructions

1. Install, activate and launch **App Settings**.
2. Locate and select your default launcher app → slide to **ON**.
3. Change **Orientation**  to `Normal rotation` if you want orientation to be synced with auto-rotation, or choose other ones based on your needs.
4. Tap "[save](https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/devices/3floppy_unmount.png)" icon next to **ON** to save settings.
5. Go back to Launcher, and as per your settings you will notice the orientation in it.

   [Default Launcher in landscape mode with auto-rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEyPY.png)

   [image: IMG: Launcher in landscape mode with auto-rotation]

   [App drawer in landscape mode with auto-rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb2TM.png)

   [image: IMG: App drawer in landscape mode with auto-rotation]

---

We're good to go!