# Any way to force an app to rotate?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, auto-rotation

I've got an app that refuses to open according to how I'm holding my phone.  So, it makes it uncomfortable to use it so I uninstalled it.  I do have auto-rotate on but I guess this app doesn't recognize it.  Is there a safe way to get apps that run upside down to work the right way?  I can't function without the home button near my left hand.

OS: 4.1
S3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the [Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate) app -- when I tested, I found that it could force any of the apps I tested to rotate.   It's a seven day free trial, then requires a license purchase (US$2.99).

It turned out that I didn't really consider the app that inspired me to download this any better when force rotated, so I did not purchase, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself, but it seems to be possible using the [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/) and its [AppSettings Module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) – provided your device is rooted.

From its announced features:

> - Force orientation (portrait/landscape/auto)

Comment: Got an Unrooted one.  :-(