# Can I rotate my camera to landscape mode with broken gyroscope?

Tags: camera, huawei, auto-rotation, gyroscope, huawei-p20

A lot of sensors on my machine are destroyed, including the gyroscope and accelerometer, because I am a terrible phone owner.
As a result, the camera does not rotate and my steps aren't counted.

Anyway, is there an artificial way to rotate my camera in landscape mode?
Is there some setting or an application I can use to fix the camera precisely?
(I checked a dozen of apps that only rotate the screen, but the camera remains in portrait mode within the landscape mode of the screen.)

My device is Huawei P20 Pro and its OS is Android 10.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Any way to force an app to rotate?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/54165/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. not a dupe. The other ticket is about a software issue. 
In my case I am trying to find software resolution to a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the Rotation Control App, with its rightmost option, image the same as auto-rotate icon, does the job for me.
E.g., streaming in Facebook is successfully affected, which was my final goal.

More details can be found here:

https://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-force-landscape-or-portrait-mode-in-apps-like-Instagram-and-others-Android_id78439