# Enable rotation of stock home screen

Tags: settings, nexus-5, home-screen, auto-rotation

How can I enable home screen rotation of Google Nexus 5(stock) with root enabled?

I've found `launcher.force_enable_rotation=true`, but it doesn't worked... Anything similar for Google Nexus 5?

Comment: Related: [How can I enable auto-rotate for the home screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support this out-of-the box, but you can swing it by using the [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/) and the [Xposed GEL Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.theknut.xposedgelsettings) module:

1. Install the [Xposed Framework installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)
2. Open the XF installer and select "Framework" at the top of the menu, then press the "Install/Update" button on the next page
3. Reboot
4. Install Xposed GEL Settings, either from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.theknut.xposedgelsettings) or via the XF installer's repo interface (the "Download" item on the main menu).
5. Launch XGELS and open the app drawer (tap the top left icon or swipe from the left edge). Select "General" from the drawer, then switch on "Rotation" on the list of settings.
6. Go into the XF installer and select "Modules" from the main menu. Check the box next to XGELS to enable the module.
7. Reboot again