# What all these partitions are for?

Tags: custom-roms, partitions, lenovo

On my Lenovo K3 Note, apart from Boot (16MB), System (2169MB), Data (5584MB) and Cache (0MB);
I can see many more partitions (in TWRP) like:

- Logo (8MB)
- Nvram (5MB)
- Recovery (16MB)
- Uboot (0MB)
- Proinfo (3MB)
- Protect (0MB)
- Parametr (0MB)
- Secro (6MB)
- Tee (10MB)
- Frp (8MB)

I'm referring to this article: http://www.cyanogenmods.org/forums/topic/take-nandroid-backup-twrp-recovery/

Which talks about PDS partition that's supposed to `keep your IMEI, modem information and all which does not affected as part of a custom ROM flashing`.

Looking at the list of partitions on my phone, I don't see `PDS`. So:

1. Where does it store IMEI and other such details?
2. If I flash a custom ROM (Lineage OS 14.1 @ https://androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=133902&sort_by=date&sort_dir=DESC) will it be able to access IMEI and other details?
3. What all these (above mentioned) partitions do?
4. Is there a way I can remove any of them (that are not needed - if any, which ones) and merge it into data partition?

Note: I've checked following questions, but couldn't really get any clarity regarding my questions.

[Lenovo Tab 2 Partition Layout](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143980/lenovo-tab-2-partition-layout)

[How to list all major partitions with their labels?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92565/how-to-list-all-major-partitions-with-their-labels)

[What are the Android system default partitions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169715/what-are-the-android-system-default-partitions)

[What Android parts do these terms describe?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59491/what-android-parts-do-these-terms-describe)

Comment: Have you already checked with our [partitions tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/partitions/info)? It explains some, and points to others – e.g. [Android Partitions Explained: boot, system, recovery, data, cache & misc](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/). Also see [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46934/16575). One that might not be coverred (thanks for naming!) is `FRP`, which obviously is used for Factory Reset Protection (see our [factory-reset tag-wiki](/tags/factory-reset/info))

Comment: @Izzy ... I've not checked these links... will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer), if the links taken together have the details :) Some partitions you've named might be device-specific (I've e.g. never seen Secro or Tee on any of my devices).